# "dest.on is not a function" error when stream file using GridFSBucket MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

"dest.on is not a function" error when stream file using GridFSBucket MongoDB

```js
app.get('/api/:id', (req, res) => {
  var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(mydb, {
    bucketName: 'ls-config',
  })
  var downStream = bucket.openDownloadStream(req.params.id);
  downStream.pipe(res);
})
```